# How to autmatically start javascript and keep it waiting for input

Tags: javascript

I am currently programming a financial calculator with javascript which is working fine. The one thing that bothers me is that the user has to press a button to process the input. I'd like the script to start onload with preset values and keep running in the background, waiting for user input.

I've tried adding onload= at the beginning of my function (there is only one) but the script doesn't keep running after that.

Comment: Google: "JavaScript event listeners"

Comment: you can use onchage event of input element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) and listen for user input inside the callback function.

If you don't need any constant processing, but only require the script to run on user input, then just use a listener, no need for setInterval.

It's hard to give you a more accurate answer without seeing your code.

---

Here's an example:

```js
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');
function someProcess() {
  a.style.width == '100px' ? a.style.width = '105px' : a.style.width = '100px';
}

setInterval(someProcess, 1000);

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 49)
    a.style.color = 'yellow';
  else if (e.keyCode == 50)
    b.style.color = 'yellow';
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 4px auto;
  background: #ccf;
  border: 2px solid #99f;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">Interval</div>
<div id="b">No Interval</div>
<p>Click here to get focus and then press 1 or 2 on your keyboard</p>
```

---

If you just need to call your function when there's a keypress in the input field, you can do something like this:

```js
var res = document.getElementById('r');
function recalc(v) {
  res.textContent = v * v;
}
recalc(0);
```

```html
The square of <input type="number" onkeyup="recalc(this.value)" value="0" /> is <span id="r"></span>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this answer, the second example is exactly what I need. 
onkeyup does the job perfect.

Comment: You're welcome! Note that you can combine it with onchange as well (I didn't use it in my example, because it fires on blur and I wanted to show you instant changes).

Answer (score 0):

For the input element in your calculator, say input tag in html, call a function on onkeyup.
for example:

```
<input onkeyup="keypressed()"/>
```

by this whenever any key is pressed, the function keypressed() in javascript in called and compute the result in that function.

Comment: you may also use window.addEventListener() function but i think that will be the complex way of achieving whatever you required.

Comment: Actually, this will call the `keypressed` function only when you click the element...

Comment: You'd have to click the input field **after** you've inputted something in order to call it with the latest value.

Comment: i am supposing only one input field in the application where the values to compute are inserting. whenever any value is entered in that input, the script will run and the required computation will be performed as the result..

Comment: No, it won't, that's what I'm trying to say - the script will only run when you click the input element (to get focus). Then you can type whatever you want, but it won't run until you click it again... try it.

Comment: also it is mentioned that it is a calculator, so only one input field is enough to enter the values and perform computations..

Comment: ok i got whatever you said.. you are correct.. but there is no need to run script without any purpose.. if someone have to compute, then input will come into picture.. and then only the script is needed..

Comment: I wrote you an example in your answer to show you (I'll remove it when you see it). Yes, the background process is probably not needed.

Comment: Just to clear things, it is a calculator but has multiple inputs e.g. interest, invested capital, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`event listeners`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) on the different `input` to `trigger` `functions`

Try it out with the following code

```
<input id="input" type="text"/>
<div id="text"></div>

document.getElementById('input').onkeydown = calculate;

function calculate() {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = document.getElementById('input').value;
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yre9dt03/)

Comment: use 'onkeyup' instead of 'onkeydown'